# Converting unique_ptr<const CHAR_INFO> to const CHAR_INFO*

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

From this I know that the WriteConsoleOutput() function needs a const CHAR_INFO * argument and I am trying to figure out if there is a way for me to use the code which I have supplied or do I have to use raw pointers?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutput
The error tells me that I need to either convert the type which I supplied or just give up on the idea. I tried casting but that ended up nowhere...
I am new to smart pointers, so if there is an explaination out there, sorry.

```
std::unique_ptr<const CHAR_INFO> screenBuffer;
screenBuffer = std::make_unique<const CHAR_INFO>(consoleWidth * consoleHeight);
WriteConsoleOutput(hConsole, screenBuffer.get(), { (short)consoleWidth * (short)consoleHeight }, { 0,0 }, &consoleSmallRect);
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   '_CHAR_INFO::_CHAR_INFO(_CHAR_INFO &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to 'const _CHAR_INFO &'   Snek    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\memory  2055
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
std::unique_ptr<CHAR_INFO []> screenBuffer;
screenBuffer = std::make_unique<CHAR_INFO[]>(consoleWidth * consoleHeight);
```

I add `[]` as you need an array.
I drop `const` so you can fill it.

`std::vector<CHAR_INFO> screenBuffer(consoleWidth * consoleHeight);` is another alternative.